# Create unique pointer with make_unique and move?

Tags: c++, move, unique-ptr

I have an Entity class with a private constructor and public CreateEntity function. CreateEntity stack-allocates new entities. In my app, I'd like to use a unique pointer to the returned entity. I found a solution with a temporary unique pointer and two move instructions.
How do I write the two lines in Start() with make_unique and a single move instruction?

```
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity(const Entity&) = delete;
    Entity& operator=(const Entity&) = delete;
    Entity(Entity&&) = default;
    Entity& operator=(Entity&&) = default;
    static Entity CreateEntity();
private:
    Entity(id_t id): m_ID(id) {}
private:
    uint32_t m_ID;
};
Entity Entity::CreateEntity()
{
    static id_t currentID = 0;

    return Entity{currentID++};
}

struct Lucre : public Application
{
    bool Start();
    std::unique_ptr<Entity> m_Object;
}
bool Lucre::Start()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Entity> ptr( new Entity(std::move(Entity::CreateEntity())));
    m_Object = std::move(ptr);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but, there is no _move_ instruction. The `Start()` method looks a bit all over the place. What's its purpose, from the top... 1. Do, what? ...

Comment: Make your default constructor public, receiving no parameters, use member initialization there `: m_ID{currentID++}`, with `currentID` a static member, then just initialize the unique pointer with `m_Object = std::make_unique<Entity>();`.

Comment: Ted, There was a typo that is now fixed. In my code, it is called m_CameraObject. When I simplified the code for StackOverflow, I had overlooked one occurrence. Rturrado, This is a great alternative approach, I may actually use it in the future. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the 2 lines in `Lucre::Start()` like this:

```
m_CameraObject.reset( new Entity( Entity::CreateEntity() ) );
```

Here, the return of `Entity::CreateEntity()` is moved, but no `std::move()` is needed as the return is already prvalue.

Comment: Is `std::move` really necessary here? Isn't `Entity::CreateEntity()` already a prvalue?

Comment: @Brian - you are right - will fix.

Answer (score 2):

Just replicating the behavior of the shown lines:

```
m_CameraObject = std::make_unique<Entity>(Entity::CreateEntity());
```

This will perform a single move construction of `Entity` and a single move assignment of `std::unique_ptr` (assuming `m_CameraObject` is of type `std::unqiue_ptr<Entity>`) in addition to the non-move/copy object constructions for `Entity` and `std::unqiue_ptr` (guaranteed in C++17 or later, otherwise likely).

The `std::move` are not required in this, since both `Entity::CreateEntity()` and `std::make_unique<Entity>(Entity::CreateEntity())` are already prvalues. In your original the `std::move` around `Entity::CreateEntity()` is also redundant.

However it is difficult to tell without full code whether this is what you really want to do. It may be that letting the factory function return a `std::unique_ptr<Entity>` directly is the better option. Then a move constructor call for `Entity` wouldn't be required.

Comment: Sorry, I had renamed m_CameraObject to m_Object to simplify the code - fixed

Comment: Both `m_Object.reset( new Entity(Entity::CreateEntity()));` and `m_Object = std::make_unique<Entity>(Entity::CreateEntity());` indeed work. This is even better than what I was looking for now that there is no more move instruction. Thank you very much everybody! Thank you also for the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

I may not have understood your needs correctly, but the sample code below:

- Also implements an `Entity` object in such a way that every instance has a different ID.
- Still hides the `Entity` class implementation details. Before, you were creating an `Entity` object with `auto e = Entity::CreateInstance();`. Now, you can do the same with `auto e = Entity{};`. That is, user knows nothing about IDs in both cases.
- Simplifies the creation of heap instances of `Entity` by adding a default constructor to `Entity`. Now, you can just initialize your `Lucre::m_Object` member with `m_Object{ std::make_unique<Entity>() }`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/495PWr5n9)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>  // uint32_t
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <memory>  // make_unique, unique_ptr

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity(): m_ID{currentID++} {}
    Entity(const Entity&) = delete;
    Entity& operator=(const Entity&) = delete;
    Entity(Entity&&) = default;
    Entity& operator=(Entity&&) = default;

    auto getID() const { return m_ID; }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Entity& e) { return os << e.m_ID; }
private:
    static inline uint32_t currentID;
    uint32_t m_ID;
};

struct Lucre
{
    Lucre() : m_Object{ std::make_unique<Entity>() } {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Lucre& l) { return os << l.m_Object->getID(); }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Entity> m_Object{};
};

int main()
{
    Lucre lucre1{};
    Lucre lucre2{};
    std::cout << "lucre1 = " << lucre1 << ", lucre2 = " << lucre2 << "\n";
}

// Outputs:
//
//   lucre1 = 0, lucre2 = 1
```

Comment: You did understand correctly what I wanted to implement. Your Entity class is a bit easier w/o CreateEntity(). Thanks a lot for the help! BTW, my project can be found here  https://github.com/beaumanvienna/vulkan (see engine/scene/entity.h and application/lucre/lucre.h)

Comment: Very glad to be helpful!